# WinAPI Find out what process is currently hooking or has open sockets

Tags: c++, c, winapi

**Is there a win32 function/way to determine what processes/services/applications currently have hooks(keyboard, mouse, global keyboard, etc.)?**

Is there also a way to know if a process/service/application is uploading/downloading data? Maybe it involves detecting if an application has an open socket?

I am attempting to create my own simple computer state application. It will list all the applications/processes currently doing what. Its part of larger project I intend to make - a simple anti-virus application.

Comment: http://forum.sysinternals.com/enumerate-windows-hooks_topic23877.html and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170 should get you started

Comment: How do you define the term hook in this particular case? A hook is generally a modification (done at runtime) to a external application allowing you to run your own code before the foreign code runs. Similar to a callback.

Comment: @Paranaix I am thinking mouse, keyboard etc. hooks but really anything that a suspicious application would do. Would DLL injection fall under what you are describing as a hook?

Comment: @JakeM DLL Injection is probably the way you would setup your hooks. But there are different methods. The most simple one actually just modifies the application code at a given point to call their own function. A more advanced method makes some code unexecutable and than catchs the vector exception thrown by this violation.

Comment: @Paranaix: The technique of making the code you want to hook "unexecutable" doesn't sound very advanced and especially not very clever. You'll pay for every incovation with a SEH exception. On top of that, there are no benefits to this approach so why would you think this is an "advanced" solution?

Comment: @newgre the trick is to catch that exception and then redirecting the instruction pointer to the next instruction of the function you hooked.  The main difference is that this approach doesnt modify any code at all.

Comment: So what's the benefit? The process can still detect that it is being "hooked" in some way. It can simply enumerate all pages in the code section and check whether some have the execute bit disabled. I don't see a benefit at all. Still you pay very high costs each time your "hook" is executed.

Comment: @newgre: Yes, the code can do this but most systems don't. They will instead check function prologues.

Comment: @Mike that might be, still the proposed technique is unusable in multi threading environments. Consider what happens when function A and function B live on the same page in memory. Assume you want to hook A, but B gets hit. What do you do? If you enable execution on that page again in order to let B execute, you will lose all future events for invocations of A. You have no possibility of ever gaining control over invocations of A again, without being vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: The only thing you could do in that case, is to create an additional mapping of the library in memory and set the IP accordingly. However, this won't work if you are going to try this with ntdll.dll, since there are hard coded entry points  from the kernel into that library (e.g. exceptions are dispatched through ntdll).

Comment: No need to do that. One method is to copy the whole page and relocate all the instructions accordingly. Then whenever the exception is hit, you redirect execution to the copied page. Then there is no need to dynamically change access rights after the first time. You usually wouldn't use this technique on system libraries anyway.

Comment: Still you need relocation information and you need to recursively copy other referenced code pages, and you need a perfect disassembly listing of that whole page (this alone is an unsolvable problem in general). Also, it won't work in the ntdll case. In the end, it might work if you can make additional assumption about the code being hooked, but I wouldn't trust that solution a bit in the general case since it's just too brittle.